# How to get all unique tags from 2 collections in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have a set of tags stored in **document.tags** and **document.fields.articleTags**.

This is how I get all the tags from both namespaces, but how can I get the result merged into one array in the response from ES?

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "size": 0, 
    "aggs" : {
      "tags" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "tags" }
       },
      "articleTags" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "articleTags" }
      }
    }
}
```

**Result**

I get the tags listed in articleTags.buckets and tags.buckets. Is it possible to have the result delivered in one bucket?

```
{
   "aggregations": {
      "articleTags": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "halloween"
            }
         ]
      },
      "tags": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "news"
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can using a single `terms` aggregation with a script instead that would "join" the two arrays (i.e. add them together), it goes like this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "size": 0, 
    "aggs" : {
      "all_tags" : {
        "terms" : { "script" : "doc.tags.values + doc.articleTags.values" }
       }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order for this query to work.

Comment: Cool, I'll give that a try tomorrow. Will accept your answer as soon that's done. :-)